# KDP publishing margins and gutters

Tags: self-publishing

KDP gives margins for an 8.5" X 5.5" book that don't look right at all. What do I do? Also, I'm using Libre Office and I can't figure ut how to create a gutter. Help! Thanks.

Matthew

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same as the old Createspace the template is a bit of a scam. Large margins and the Calibri font massively increase the page count. More pages = more money.

If the margins don't look right - change them.

In LibreOffice go to *Format* then *Page*.

These are my settings for a 300 page 6"x 9" book.

**Paper size:** Width = 15.24cm Height = 22.86cm.

**Margins:** Inner = 2.29cm Outer = 1.52cm Top and Bottom 0.89cm.

Check the box to *Mirror Margins*. By setting the inner margin greater than the outer margin you have created your gutter.